# Powershell script that calls another powershell script

Tags: powershell

My Powershell script (say E:\myFolder\Script1.ps1) calls another script (say E:\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1).

On our older server (Powershell version 6.2.9200), the below code works.

On our newer server (Powershell version 10.0.17763), the below code gave this error:

```
. : The term '\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Script1.ps1:

```
param(
[Parameter(Position=0)]
$CObjectName
)
$CObjectName = "myObjectName"

. "$env:AuxDrive\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1"
$CValue = Get-CValue $CObjectName

Write-Host $CValue
```

If I remove this code, it gave another error:

```
#. "$env:AuxDrive\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1"

Get-CValue: The term 'Get-CValue' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

And, if I replace AuxDrive with E: like below (\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1 is on E drive)

```
. "$env:E:\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1"
```

It gave this error

```
. : The term '\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1' is not recognized as the name of 
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling 
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
```

E:\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1 exists.
How can I fix this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: It seems like your AuxDrive variable is not set in your environment variables

Comment: It seems you've stated Windows version (or BuildVersion) and not PowerShell version (PSVersion). Please consider including the content of `$PSVersionTable` in your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the script `Get-CValue.ps1` is available on your new system.
Contact the creator and ask them about how to install it properly.

Comment: E:\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1 does exists. I edited my original post. When replacing AuxDrive with E: , I am getting a different error.

Comment: You can't use two drive references. Either it's E: or it's ENV: Not both. So try gong with  . 'E:\myFolder\Get-CValue.ps1' to dot source load the script. Or set the environment variable Auxdrive to E:

Comment: Setting environment variables using PowerShell is usually only done for the current user... [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-5.1)